# Custom Menus Description Stripping HTML Tags

Tags: menus

Spent two days researching this. I need to be able to add HTML to the Custom Menus Description. Everything I can find (including on this site) is from Feb 2011 and mentions using a strip_tags filter. However, that no longer works. I'm developing on WP 3.4 Beta 4.

I've created a custom walker class and found a filter to remove HTML tags and put the following into functions.php:

```
// Custom Walker Class to extend Default Nav Menu
class Description_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth, $args)
{
    $classes     = empty ( $item->classes ) ? array () : (array) $item->classes;

    $class_names = join(
        ' '
    ,   apply_filters(
            'nav_menu_css_class'
        ,   array_filter( $classes ), $item
        )
    );

    ! empty ( $class_names )
        and $class_names = ' class="'. esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"';

// Build default menu items
    $output .= "<li id='menu-item-$item->ID' $class_names>";

    $attributes  = '';

    ! empty( $item->attr_title )
        and $attributes .= ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->target )
        and $attributes .= ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->xfn )
        and $attributes .= ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"';
    ! empty( $item->url )
        and $attributes .= ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"';

// Build the description
    $description = ( ! empty ( $item->description ) and 1 == $depth )
        ? '<span class="nav_desc">' . esc_html( $item->description ) . '</span>' : '';

    $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

    $item_output = $args->before
        . "<a $attributes>"
        . $args->link_before
        . $title
        . '</a> '
        . $args->link_after
        . $description
        . $args->after;

    // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
    $output .= apply_filters(
        'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
    ,   $item_output
    ,   $item
    ,   $depth
    ,   $args
    );
}
}

// Allow HTML descriptions in WordPress Menu
remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item', 'cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item' );
function cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item( $menu_item ) {
       $menu_item->description = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_description',  $menu_item-  >post_content );
       return $menu_item;
}
```

Then used the following to spit out the menu:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'menu sf-menu', 'walker' => new Description_Walker )); ?>
```

However, the html tags are still be stripped! See the **Screen Shots:**

[Menu Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtqXS.png)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jE0GI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Untested). But if you want to use HTML in the description, then you shouldn't use:

```
`esc_html( $item->description )`
```

Try removing the `esc_html` as this escapes the HTML. (Or better still use [`wp_kses`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) instead to only allow certain tags.).

So you want

```
$description = ( ! empty ( $item->post_content ) and 1 == $depth )
    ? '<span class="nav_desc">' .$item->post_content . '</span>' : '';
```

And you still want the `remove_filter( 'nav_menu_description', 'strip_tags' );`, but the `cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item` function is unnecessary.

Although I don't in the above example, I would recommend using `wp_kses`.

Comment: Changed it to esc_attr. Still getting this result: `<span class="nav_desc"> &lt;strong&gt;Snowboarder&lt;/strong&gt; &lt;img src=&quot;http://fmg.gregrickaby.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/nav-aimee-fuller.jpg&quot;&gt;</span></li>`

Comment: @Greg No, remove _any_ escaping.

Comment: @Greg `esc_attr` is really the same as `esc_html`. If you want to use HTML in the description, you don't want to escape any HTML - (or escape *some* with `wp_kses`). See update answer.

Comment: That worked! Thank you! However, I needed to keep the `cus_wp_setup_nav_menu_item function`. Remove it stripped the HTML.  Here is the full working code: http://pastebin.com/XmjtUyAg

Comment: This is correct, we have to manually re-attach `post_content` to `$menu_item->description` attribute, because `add_filter nav_menu_description` only passes text value as an argument https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.3/src/wp-includes/nav-menu.php#L915