# Adding line breaks to nav menu items

Tags: menus

I need to add line breaks to the nav menu item titles.  I didn't realize this was a problem as when I am logged in as a Super Admin, I can add `<br/>` just fine, but apparently regular-level admins cannot.

I've read over this post
[Custom Menus Description Stripping HTML Tags](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51609/custom-menus-description-stripping-html-tags)

but I'm fairly convinced the tags are being stripped on on save/update, so I am not immediately seeing how a Custom Walker is the solution, but my brain is pretty well shot today, so it might be obvious.

There also doesn't seem to be any sanitation happening in `wp_save_nav_menu_items()` or `wp_update_nav_menu_item()`.

Comment: This must be specific to multisites since an admin on a single-site install can use the `<br/>` tag... In any case menu items are post types, so I think the sanitisation is in `sanitize_post_field()` (specifically `title_save_pre` - see [source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/3.5.1/wp-includes/kses.php#L1329)). Unfortunately there's no way to circumvent that for *just* menu titles - so your posted solution is probably the best.

Comment: Yeah I thought I remembered that you could... so never realized it was a problem until a client complained.  Thanks for the source link.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Following the hint from @Rarst regarding safe characters here's what I ended up doing:

```
function wpa_105883_menu_title_markup( $title, $id ){
    if ( is_nav_menu_item ( $id ) && ! is_admin() ){
        $title = preg_replace( '/#BR#/', '<br/>', $title );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpa_105883_menu_title_markup', 10, 2 );
```

**Edit**: Also per Rarst's comment I've replaced the `preg_replace` with `str_ireplace`

```
function wpa_105883_menu_title_markup( $title, $id ){
    if ( is_nav_menu_item ( $id ) ){
        $title = str_ireplace( "#BR#", "<br/>", $title );
    }
    return $title;
}
add_filter( 'the_title', 'wpa_105883_menu_title_markup', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Given that it's not really _regular_ expression, I'd just use generic [`str_ireplace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) for replace. Also didn't know `is_nav_menu_item()`, cool. :)

Comment: I just discovered `is_nav_menu_item()` while reading through some code for this question. It was new to me too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is a way to no affect all the titles? Because this affect all, even in dashboard.

Comment: Just check that it isn't `is_admin()` then.

Comment: Nice, and with "<br class='break' />" you can make it responsive.

Answer (score 3):

Sans turning sanitization logic inside out or coding custom interface for it... I would just designate some safe character for it (for example pipe `|`) and replace it with break tag on output.

It passes through `the_title` filter in walker, would only need to timely add and remove the filter so it does not affect titles elsewhere.

Comment: Yup!  That's exactly what I just discovered. I ended up using #BR# as a safe character.  Will post.

Comment: How you can do it to no affect all the titles?